# What happened to the OPs blue background?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Isn't there a bluish background behind the "profile" thingy of the poster?

[image: Isn't there a background that is blue?]

Comment: Considering the cell now reads as `<td class="post-signature owner)">` in the source, I'm guessing someone botched the code there. Random parentheses!

Comment: Why does your arrow have two arrow heads? I demand an explanation! This is clear maltreatment of freehand red things.

Comment: @Doorknob Who knows. I drew this cause I was bored, and screwed up cause I was tired... -_- |

Comment: On the iOS app you're pointing to the wrong corner.....

Comment: @angussidney What? How do you know? There's no blue! (Shhh... You're not supposed to say anything!)

Comment: Deleted posts look even stranger: http://i.imgur.com/lwjWA7h.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like that slipped in during some code cleanups yesterday (or rather, wasn't properly removed with the cleaned up code).

I've removed the offending `)` - fix will be with you in the next build.

Comment: What is this for kind of fix? You surely meant to correct the CSS to `.owner\) { .. }`. :3